# Prove an integration inequality $\int_{0}^{1}\,\left(\int_{0}^{x}\,f(y)\,{\rm d}y\right)^2{\rm d}x\leqslant -\frac{mM}{6(M-m)^2}(3m^2-8mM+3M^2)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Suppose that a function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the following conditions:

1. $\int_{0}^{1}\,f(x)\,{\rm d}x=0$, and
2. $f\in R[0,1] $.

Prove that $$\int_{0}^{1}\,\left(\int_{0}^{x}\,f(y)\,{\rm d}y\right)^2\,{\rm d}x\leqslant
-\frac{mM}{6(M-m)^2}(3m^2-8mM+3M^2)\,,$$
where $m:=\min\limits_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)$ and $M:=\max\limits_{x\in[0,1]} f(x)$.

Comment: Posts that merely state a problem are discouraged on this site. You can edit your post to include the *source* of the problem, its *motivation*, and your own thoughts and attempts at solving it. Think of a question here as a small blog post about a problem which helps others see why it is of interest to you.

Comment: I am conjecturing that this stronger inequality holds: $$\int_0^1\,\left(\int_0^x\,f(y)\,\text{d}y\right)^2\,\text{d}x\leq \frac{1}{3}\,\left(\frac{mM}{M-m}\right)^2\,.$$

Comment: What does $f\in R[0,1]$ mean?  Does it mean $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$?  If this is the case, the minimum or the maximum value of $f$ on $[0,1]$ may not exist, and perhaps, the infimum and the supremum should be used instead.